# Triggering a MySQL procedure at a timed interval

Tags: mysql, timed-events

I am wondering if there is a way to trigger a procedure by a timed interval. I am trying to create new tables dynamically and have the procedure written to do so, I just need a way to trigger it. I can easily write a python script and run it as a scheduled  task. I am wondering if there is a way to do this within MySQL server. I know MS Server has server agent, I am wondering if MySQL server has something similar?

EDIT:

blockheads comment below worked. Should be noted that this only works on MySQL Server 5.1 or later

```
CREATE EVENT myEvent ON SCHEDULE EVERY INTERVAL 5 minutes DO CALL myProcedure();
```

Comment: I think you can do 
`CREATE EVENT myEvent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY INTERVAL 5 minutes
DO
  CALL myProcedure();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html)